# Get system's "list separator" character using C++/STL

Tags: c++, stl, locale

In my C++ software, I use:

```
std::stringstream str;
str.imbue(std::locale(""));
char decimal_separator = std::use_facet< std::numpunct<char> >(str.getloc()).decimal_point();
```

To retrieve system's (Windows) decimal separator (specified by using in "Windows Control Panel | Region and Language | Formats | Additional settings...").

In the same Window Control Panel dialog, user also specifies a "list separator" (to be used to separate values in a csv file).

From C++/STL code, how can I access this "list separator" character"? I did not find anything in [locale documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to use the Windows API for this.

Comment: I think you’re saying C++ && STL not ||, but GetLocaleInfoEx will do the trick. I think LOCALE_SLIST is the constant.

Comment: As far as I know there's no support for CSV files in the standard library. But that's perhaps a good thing, because the Microsoft way of assuming the CSV files use national number and separator conventions, means that a Norwegian cannot just send his CSV-file to an English person, or vice versa. The Microsoft way really sucks, it's beyond comprehension that a global company can have people who could design that, so it's just nice that C++ doesn't support that. Use the C locale for CSV files. Require readers (even using Excel) to handle that. That's portable.

Comment: The C in CSV stands for Comma. Use it.

Comment: I agree csv sucks. However, if I use "." for decimal separator and "," for list separator, then, my CSV won't open properly in Microsoft Excel. As all our computers are using a French version of Excel and French settings, I'd like to pickup the appropriate decimal separator (",") and list separator (";") to have the file be smartly handled by Excel.

Comment: Excel will usually open tab-separated docs just fine

Comment: @zzxyz: Just tested, mine does not. CSV with tabs is not separated in columns when opened in Excel.

Comment: Add `"sep=,"` as a first line, including the quotes, and don't use other tools than Microsoft Excel (it's very Excel-specific). Works fine with my old Excel 2013. https://superuser.com/questions/773644/what-is-the-sep-metadata-you-can-add-to-csvs

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That's nice. Unfortunately we also read the file with other tools (and programs), so I'd like to stick with a "standard" format with no header.

Comment: @jpo38: Well, you can import an English CSV file, specifying the item and decimals separators in the import wizard, and record that as macro. I checked and macros still work in Excel 2013 (one just has to unhide the Developer tab first). Then use the generated code as basis for an "Open English-format CSV file", and ditto for saving?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That' would work, but it's really a pain to deploy this on all computers we have...for now, I use "," list seperator if decimal separator is "." and I use ";" list seperator if decimal separator is ",". This is hardcoded in my code generating csv files. If I find a way to pickup system's list separator character (rather than hardcoding it), that would be nice, else, I'll stay with the hardcoded values...that's definitely the easiest approach as the file gets opened smartly by Excel by just double-clicking it.

Comment: "all our computers are using a French version of Excel" Then use hardcoded French separators and don't query anything. Problem solved.

Comment: From long and bitter experience: the format Excel likes best is UTF-16LE with BOM, tab-separated, with C-locale formatted numbers. Add a space in front for any text field that begins with `+`, `-` or `=`, otherwise Excel tries to parse it as a formula. Excel opens such a file correctly regardless of the system locale settings, even on a Mac (there exists Office for Mac). To have Excel produce this format, save as "Unicode Text File".